# stop keyboard from shifting app up and enabling scroll in IOS 7/8

Tags: ios, html, cordova, keyboard

We have an app that is a fixed width and height and does not allow the user to scroll. As part of this app we have a navbar that is fixed to the screen under the status area. This all works great.

The problem is that when a keyboard is shown, it shifts our app window up to make room for the keyboard. At this point its possible to scroll our app and the titlebar which should be fixed to the top is no longer on screen.

Ideally the keyboard would still show, but our app window would resize so its not as tall, but items fixed to the top are still fixed to the top. also, you should not be able to scroll the window at this point.

Comment: What keyboard plugin are you using? If you are not using any, try the Ionic keyboard plugin.

Comment: Thanks! Iconic keyboard does in fact solve our problems!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as Sani mentioned in a comment the Iconic keyboard plugin does in fact do what I'm looking for:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard

using:

`cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);`
`cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);`